# Discord bot on replit does not respond but online on server

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to make a dc bot on replit like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SPTfmiYiuok)
my code is:

```
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("This is user {0.user}".format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  if message.content.startswith("$hello"):
    await message.channel.send("Hello!")

my_secret = os.environ['TOKEN']

client.run(my_secret)
```

My bot is not responding to my command but it is online and I checked the permissions

[image: console on replit]

[image: It is on my server with all important permissions]

Answer (score 0):

You most likely do not have enabled **MESSAGE CONTENT INTENT** in **Privileged Gateway Intents**. You can find that on discord dev portal website.

If that doesn't work, double check your server and bot permissions.